phpMailer CC issue with multiple recipients
My database has 75 email addresses. I use a form to pass variables to the sendmail.php file. When a cc email address is passed to sendmail.php and is processed, I get 75 copies of the cc email in my inbox.
I added $mail->clearAddresses() ; but that has not helped.
What am I doing wrong>
I would like to send one email to each person in the database plus one copy to the cc recipient.Here is my current code:
<?php

/**
     * Send email to a list of recipients with phpMailer.
 */

//============================================================ database connection
//   code goes here
// ============================================================= end db connection

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

//===================================================================
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
     $administrator=    $_POST['administrator'] ;
     $sender=           $_POST['sender'];
     $from=             $_POST['sender'];
     $from_email=       $_POST['from_email'] ;
     $replyto=          $_POST['from_email'] ;
     $subject=          $_POST['subject'] ;
    $message =          $_POST['message'];
     $cc=               $_POST['cc'] ;
     $sig_block=        $_POST['sig_block'] ;
     $fileName=         $_POST['fileName'] ;

     $location = "PHPMailer/attachments/";
     $subject =  "$subject";
     $message =  "$message<p>$sig_block";

//===============================
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
//Server settings
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
      
        $mail->Host          = 'smtp.xxx.com'; 
        $mail->Username      = 'email address';
        $mail->Password      = 'password';

        $mail->SMTPSecure    = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;  
        $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
        $mail->Port          = 587;

//Attachment
        if(strlen($fileName) >=4) {
            $mail->addAttachment($location.$fileName);
        }

//Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->Body = $message; 
        
//Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('email@domain', 'Webmaster'); 
        if(strlen($cc) >=4) {
            $mail->addCC($cc);
            }
        $mail->addReplyTo($replyto, $sender);   //Reply to sender email
        $mail->addAddress($from_email, $sender);  //copy sent to sender

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

// Access database 
     $sql= $conn->prepare("
          SELECT fname, lname, email 
          FROM members
          WHERE year_pd = '$year'
          ORDER BY lname
     ");

     $sql->execute(); 
     while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {  
           $fname= $row['fname']; 
           $lname= $row['lname']; 
           $to= $row['email'];

          $mail->clearAddresses() ;

}  // close while

} // close try
 catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
 


Firstly, read the docs on sending to lists.
You're missing that addAddress() adds an address to a message, it doesn't set who the message is going to, so if you keep calling it in a loop with send(), each message will progressively be sent to more and more addresses.
Read the docs for full advice, but the primary thing is that you need to call clearAddresses() after calling send() inside your loop to reset the recipient list.
